# RXJS ERROR TypeError: "this._subscribe is not a function"

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular7

I get the following error and I was not able to resolve it.

> ERROR TypeError: "this._subscribe is not a function"

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRkgD.png) is also the full stack trace in form of an image.

**What I try to achieve**
I have a class called *ChargingStation* that has several attributes and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiMXG.png). The instances of this class should be fetched from my api. This functionality is delivered by a class called *ChargingStationService*. The corresponding method inside the *ChargingStationService* class is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQAJe.png). Currently I just try to deliver a mocked Observable back. The *getChargingStation* method will be called from my *ChargingStationComponent* that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENWtI.png). The retrieved *ChargingStation* object should be shown inside the components view via DataBinding. But the DataBinding ist not working / Nothing is shown. It used to work with the service returning just an object of type *ChargingStation* rather than an *Observable*

**What the application flow is like**

In the *ngOnInit* method of the *ChargingStationComponent* it gets the id specified in the url */charging-station/{id}*.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChargingStation(+this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
```

With this id the *getChargingStation(id)* method is called.

```js
  getChargingStation(id: number): void {
    console.log(this.chargingStationService.getChargingStation(id));
    this.chargingStationService.getChargingStation(id)
      .subscribe(chargingStation => (this.chargingStation = chargingStation));
  }
```

This method internally uses the injected *ChargingStationService* that will retrieve the *ChargingStations* from the API in the future. Currently this method looks like this and should return a mocked observable of a charging station.

```js
 getChargingStation(id: number): Observable<ChargingStation> {
    let searchedChargingStation= new ChargingStation(
      id,
      false,
      0.37,
      this.plugs,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      "Store Street, R802"
    );
    let observableSearchedChargingStation = Observable.create(searchedChargingStation);
    console.log(observableSearchedChargingStation);
    return observableSearchedChargingStation;
  }
```

**What I´ think is wrong**
I think the Observable.create method might be the wrong choice but i didn't find anything more suitable yet.

I hope some of you can help me out :) Thanks a lot and merry Christmas

Greetings
Jan

Comment: I think you should use `return of(searchedChargingStation);` from service method. RXjs v6+ has `of` fro creating Observables.

Comment: `Observable.create` takes a function, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't push the new value to your observer once you created it:)

instead of

```
let observableSearchedChargingStation = Observable.create(searchedChargingStation);
```

do:

```
Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.next(searchedChargingStation);
});
```

and your code should work the way it is.

Comment: perfect. It also worked with the solution that @nicraft supposed. I had to do  -- import { of } from 'rxjs'; -- at first. Both of your solutions worked. Thanks a lot, stackoverflow helped once again :)